# Search performance issue with a search query

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, search

I have a performance issue with a query. I have a table with companies (bedrijf) and a table with categories. I want to do a search query that takes all companies with the search wordt in the company name, and I want to take all companies that are in a category where the category name contains the search wordt.

I made this query (search wordt is: marko):

```
/*8 seconds*/
 SELECT b.id,b.plaats
      FROM bedrijf AS b
      INNER JOIN bedrijf_categorie AS bc ON bc.bedrijfid = b.id
      WHERE b.naam LIKE '%marko%'
        OR bc.categorieid IN
          (SELECT id
           FROM categorie
           WHERE naam LIKE '%marko%')
```

Or this one, still testing what is faster with a big database:

```
/*7.6 seconds*/
SELECT b.id,b.plaats
      FROM bedrijf AS b
      INNER JOIN bedrijf_categorie AS bc ON bc.bedrijfid = b.id
      INNER JOIN categorie AS c ON bc.categorieid = c.id
      WHERE b.naam LIKE '%marko%' OR c.naam LIKE '%marko%';
```

When I do the queries separately it is a lot faster:

```
/*0.84 seconds*/
SELECT b.id,b.plaats
      FROM bedrijf AS b
      WHERE b.naam LIKE '%marko%'

/*2.39 seconds*/      
SELECT b.id,b.plaats
      FROM bedrijf AS b
      INNER JOIN bedrijf_categorie AS bc ON bc.bedrijfid = b.id
      WHERE bc.categorieid IN
          (SELECT id
           FROM categorie
           WHERE naam LIKE '%marko%')
```

How can I do those queries in one query without the performance lost. The database contains 500.000 records in bedrijf and 500.000 records in bedijf_categorie.

Comment: Query performances depend on *many* factors, most of them being *specific* to your database. When you have a "performance problem" with one of your query, you *first reflex* should be to use [`EXPLAIN`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain.html) to see how the various index are used (or not) and to estimate the number of row examined.

Answer (score 1):

You could make a [UNION](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html) when you can't find a better solution:

```
(SELECT b.id,b.plaats
      FROM bedrijf AS b
      INNER JOIN bedrijf_categorie AS bc ON bc.bedrijfid = b.id
      WHERE bc.categorieid IN
          (SELECT id
           FROM categorie
           WHERE naam LIKE '%marko%')) UNION
(SELECT b.id,b.plaats
      FROM bedrijf AS b
      WHERE b.naam LIKE '%marko%')
```